# Selenium IDE: Verifying a dynamic pattern in a website using RegExp

Tags: regex, selenium-ide

I am trying to verify the presence of the dynamic string "6:20 AM – 6:46 AM" in [this website](http://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/usa/dallas) in selenium IDE using Regular Expressions but it doesn't work. I can't use XPath since the numbers keep changing and I am looking for only certain numbers. If I use XPath, it will match the string no matter what the numbers are. What is wrong with the following?

Command: verifyTextPresent

Target:  regexp:[6]\:[0-9]{2} [AP]M \– [6]\:[0-9]{2} [AP]M

This question seems too simple but not in real, please check your solution and see if it really works on the aforementioned website. Please note that my question is not only about RegExp! I'm asking about using RegExp in Selenium IDE.

Comment: `6:20 AM – 6:46 AM` where do you match `:` in your regex.

Comment: try `[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} [AP]M – [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} [AP]M`

Comment: \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(\s*[AP]M)?\s*[-–]\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(\s*[AP]M)?

Answer (score 0):

Does your string have anything before it - Perhaps escaping it with backspaces queries

```
\s
```

might be advisable?

```
Sunrise Today: 6:19 AM
Sunset Today: 8:38 PM
```

Notice how there is a gap before the 6 begins.

So a potential output code here would be

```
\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+\ [AP]M
\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+\ [AP]M
```

The fellow above restricts it to 1 or 2 using {1,2}, and technically this is more accurate, but mine is more shorthand, and on a timing website where you will only get 1 or 2, my method would work (Regex '+' is 1 or more instances).